# Can you scale an image that is loaded with css

Tags: jquery, css

I am unable to edit the HTML , so i have to load some caption images using css

Is it possible to scale those images using css as well ?

Sample HTML

```
<div class="report">
<td id="rome">
<h3></h3>
</td>
</div>
```

need to load an image for either #rome or h3 , doesn't matter which one , but need to scale it

```
td#rome {background:url(myimage.jpg);}
```

or

```
report h3 {background:url(myimage.jpg);}
```

I am able to add jquery to the site if needed , if that is a possiblity

Comment: you mean like background-size:cover? or background-size:contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't "style" a website with JS/JQuery

Second, there is the `background-size` property

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: careful - people here love to downvote anyone linking to w3fools

Comment: why should I c/p content that is lovely put together in a pretty understandable way?

Comment: We avoid W3Schools on SO because it is often wrong, incomplete, and broken. We prefer more reputable references like W3.org (*unrelated to W3Schools*) and developer.mozilla.org

Comment: Jeah but it's more clearly arranged and often just what you need, if you need just a quick check on syntax.